# Get input from LBUTTON

Tags: c++

In the past few days I have tried making an autoclicker. I want it to click when you hold down your LBUTTON, but it doesn't work. It will work with every other key like RBUTTON or even a keyboard key like LSHIFT but it wont with LBUTTON.

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be? Thanks a lot.

It looks like the event works as it is impossible to drag items like normally when activated, but it will not actually simulate clicks.

```
if (activated && (GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x8000)) {
        flag = true;
        randomize = (rand() % 13 + 7) / 10;
        delay = randomize * (1000 / kps);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(delay);
}
```

Comment: is that part of a message pump? > please provide a minimal, complete example and define "not working": VK not detected, or events are sent  but have no effect, ...?

Comment: could it be that with emitting a MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN on left down, the double click detection of the OS is triggered?

Comment: and what could i do to disable or bypass this?

Comment: cancel the initial event